# Issue while writing data from databricks to Azure DW (synapse)

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-synapse

Trying to write data into SQl DW through databricks stream data frame. process is trying to delete the temp folder in the BLOB storage and throwing below. In the documentation i see that process will not automatically cleanup tempdir. Is it true? if true, then why is this error? Using below query in python

```
df1.writeStream
.format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")
.option("url", sqlDwUrlSmall)
.option("tempDir", tempDir)
.option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true")
.option("dbTable", "SampleTable")
.option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp_checkpoint_location1")
.option("numStreamingTempDirsToKeep", -1)
.start()
```

ERROR AzureNativeFileSystemStore: Encountered Storage Exception for delete on Blob: https://savupputest1.blob.core.windows.net/container1/tempDirs/2019-12-20/21-27-29-347/adca2ed6-a705-4274-8c24-0f0e3d7c64a7/batch0, Exception Details: This operation is not permitted on a non-empty directory. Error Code: DirectoryIsNotEmpty
19/12/20 21:27:32 ERROR AzureNativeFileSystemStore: Failed while attempting to delete key tempDirs/2019-12-20/21-27-29-347/adca2ed6-a705-4274-8c24-0f0e3d7c64a7/batch0

Answer (score 0):

Before you start, make sure “tempDir” a wasbs URI. We recommend you use a dedicated Blob storage container for the SQL DW.

Here is the python example for structured streaming.

```
# Set up the Blob storage account access key in the notebook session conf.
spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key.chepra.blob.core.windows.net",
  "gv7nVXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXldlOiA==")

# Prepare streaming source; this could be Kafka, Kinesis, or a simple rate stream.
df = spark.readStream \
  .format("rate") \
  .option("rowsPerSecond", "100000") \
  .option("numPartitions", "16") \
  .load()

# Apply some transformations to the data then use
# Structured Streaming API to continuously write the data to a table in SQL DW.

df.writeStream \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://chepra.database.windows.net:1433;database=chepradw;user=chepra@chepra;password=XXXXXXXXXXX;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;") \
  .option("tempDir", "wasbs://data-files@chepra.blob.core.windows.net/data-files") \
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") \
  .option("dbTable", "chepradw") \
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp_checkpoint_location") \
  .start()
```

**Output of the Notebook:**

[image]

For more details, refer “[Azure Databricks – Azure SQL DW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/sql-data-warehouse?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-ca%2Fazure%2Fazure-databricks%2FTOC.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-ca%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json#usage-streaming)”.

Hope this helps. Do let us know if you any further queries.

---

Do click on "Mark as Answer" and Upvote on the post that helps you, this can be beneficial to other community members.